# Changing visibility in a userControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, winrt-xaml

i got an userControl with a button

```
<Button Content="Button" x:Name="button"/>
```

in the codebehind

```
public Button button { get; set; }
```

I use this userControl in another page

CrudPage

```
 <UC:MyUC x:Name="objectForm" />
```

is possible to modify visibily of this button from the codebehind of the CrudPage?

Comment: Expose a property on your usercontrol that will set/unset the visibility of your button

Comment: i'm pretty noob...how?

Comment: Look at the answer you got from dkozi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DenedencyProperty` in `UserControl`:

```
public static DependencyProperty ButtonVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MyUserControl), null);

public Visibility ButtonVisibility
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ButtonVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
}
```

bind it to `Button.Visibility`:

```
<Button 
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ButtonVisibility}" 
    Content="Button" 
    x:Name="button"/>
```

assuming that `UserControl` has a `x:Name="userControl"`

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="userControl">
```

you should be able to control `Visibility` of a `Button` from outside like so:

```
<local:MyUserControl ButtonVisibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Comment: DependencyProperty.Register needs 4 arguments ... i add new PropertyMetadata("")... but it doesn't work, i've deleted the elementName from the button, and it works

Comment: Sorry, in WPF there is overload with 3 arguments, in your case `null` as 4th parameter should do just fine. I've updated my answer

Comment: Depends how many buttons you have inside. `Button.Click` is already bubbling event so you can catch it directly on `UserControl` without additional code `<local:MyUserControl ... Button.Click="MyHandler"`. It will trigger for every `Button` in `UserControl` so if you have more then one `Button` you'll need to check `e.OriginalSource`